# Send email when JButton is clicked?

Tags: java, email, smtp

Someone please please be thorough and help me with this, I've been at this forever now. I'm somewhat new to programming and I've never set up a server or anything before. I get this error trying to run my program.  "`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`" and "`javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;`"

**Here's my code**:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
if (jButton1.isEnabled());
Properties sessionProperties = System.getProperties();
String to = "bleh@gmail.com";
    String from = "bleh@gmail.com"; 
    String host = "localhost"; 
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try{
     // Create a default MimeMessage object.
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

     // Set From: header field of the header.
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

     // Set To: header field of the header.
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              new InternetAddress(to));

     // Set Subject: header field
     message.setSubject("Infomation");

     // Now set the actual message
     message.setText("Hello!");

     // Send message
     Transport.send(message);

    }catch (MessagingException mex) {
     mex.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code came from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm
If so, I'd like to direct you to the sentence in the tut

```
Here it is assumed that your localhost is connected to the internet and capable enough
to send an email.
```

By capable, it means that you have an SMTP server running on localhost; the reason why you got the exception was because `Transport` attempted to use an SMTP server on localhost:25 to send the mail.

Your options are then to either run an SMTP server locally (a real pain) or to use a third-party SMTP (GMail, Amazon SES, etc.) service to send the mail.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and response!! Please explain how I can use a third party SMTP with the code above? I know I can't use public class and all of that in an action listener, which is why I haven't used any other code. I greatly appreciate your response.

Comment: Take a look at this example of using Gmail as an SMTP service: http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

If you opt to go with a more enterprise-y option (I don't know the scope of the code you're writing), Amazon SES is probably your best option. It has a well-developed SDK (see here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-java.html) and integrates well with other Amazon services.

Comment: I looked at that example but he starts it off stating a public class which I can't do within an action listener. (Or at least I'm not sure as to how.) If so, how do I use that code within an action listener? Thank you so much for your response!

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean by "I can't [use a public class] within an action listener".

That said, the essential elements of the example is the code within the `main` method, namely the setting of properties and use of a `javax.mail.Authenticator` in your `Session.getInstance()` call.

Otherwise, there's nothing different between your code and the code in the example; just the use of additional properties and the Authenticator.

Comment: When I try to use a main method within an action listener like " private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {" I always get the illegal expression error and then when I add the bracket it screws with other parts of my code, as in cutting off certain parts and disconnecting them from their variables etc. And I have to put the code in there in order for the instance to occur on click of the JButton. Also again thank you for helping me with this. I apologize if it seems as if I'm not getting what you're trying to say, I'm fairly new to Java.

Comment: Ahah. Your issue isn't with public, but rather with the fact that `main` methods are `static`, meaning they can't be accessed from non-static contexts (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html has a reasonably good treatment of `static`). However, that doesn't mean that you can't yank the code out of a `static` method (like the `main` in the example) and put it in a non-static method or even directly place it in your private method.